# if element appears, how to close?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation, appium

What command would I use to close this element, **ONLY** if it appears during runtime. I want my code to be able to notice when it appears but, if it does not appear, then continue with regular priority.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the HTML code ?

Answer (score 3):

```
//You can change ExpectedConditions type (visibilityOfElementLocated)
public boolean isExist(By elementBy, int seconds) {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(elementBy));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

//if popup is displayed within 3 seconds
By POPUP = By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/parentPanel");

if (isExist(POPUP, 3)) {
    //do something - for example click cancel button
}
```

Comment: im using android

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the number of elements matching with the id/class and then click only if you have atleast 1 element.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/parentPanel"));
if (elements.size()>0){
    elements.get(0).click();
}
```